# Terraform creates aws resources according to Cloudshell CLI but doesn't show up on Management Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-lex

I'm new to terraform but I created an Amazon lex chatbot with terraform from this [repo](https://github.com/jzbruno/terraform-aws-lex-examples/tree/main/schedule-appointment) and the AWS management console doesn't show that the resources are created.

I'm in the same region and I ran terraform apply. I checked my Terraform State s3 bucket and cloudtrails see if it registered any activity and it shows that the commands are run and an ARN for the Lex-bot exists. But it won't show up in the management console. Is it hidden by default or something?

Comment: So you have followed the instructions from the README file?